# Android hide row in a list view

Tags: android, listview, contacts

In my android application I am taking contacts from contact list and storing in list arrays.this contact list I am showing in my app for selection..In contact list normally users may store atm pins, pass book number etc... so i want to avoid storing of any number below 10 digits. Here the problem is I am storing contacts name to one list array and contact number to another list array. If I am removing numbers only..then it is difficult for me to remove the corresponding contact names..I am giving my code below.. can anyone help me with a solution

```
String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, null);
            tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.selected);
            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            //tv.setSelected(true);
            tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


            String phnoCheckTendigits = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(phnoCheckTendigits.length() < 10)
            {
                vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } 
}
```

I didi like this.. but here I am getting empty rows..

//Dear friends I found a solution...it worked...I am giving it below..and I am accepting Danieles answer... because it is very good answer.. I did in my way ..thats y I am adding it here

```
 int idx = 0;

                while (idx < phno1.size())
                {
                    if(phno1.get(idx).length() < 10)
                    {
                        // Remove item
                        phno1.remove(idx);
                        name1.remove(idx);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ++idx;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Try to remove that object from arraylist before pass to getView method.

Comment: Why aren't you using a model class which takes a name and a phone number and put it into a list? it would be a lot easier to manage than two different arrays.

Comment: @Danielle...Can u help me

Comment: Instead of two lists, try to use `LinkedHashMap` in which put number as key and name as value or you can use as per requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a Model class which has two parameters, Name and Number, then create a List which you could either get from Contacts, create yourself or let the user create it. Once you have the list you can easily manage it, add and remove items.

This is a Model class example:

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Model(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
}

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getNumber() { return this.number; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setNumber(String number) {this.number = number; }
```

}

Then maybe have a different class to create a List:

```
public class ModelList {
    private List<Model> list;

    public void createList() {
        list.add(new Model("name", "0123456789"));
        ...
    }

    public List<Model> getList() { return list; }
}
```

Easy enough, if you want to remove an element from the list you have:

```
list.removeAt(position /* int */); //if you want to remove a specific position
```

or

```
list.remove(Model); // if you want to remove a specific model
```

**Note:** I wouldn't limit the user to have numbers >= 10, your app would be useless in some countries where the phone numbers are smaller, or even for emergency number which are usually made out of 3 characters.

Comment: Yes I know.. Danielle...but this app..is for only using in India.. where mobile number is 10 digits only

Comment: It was a side note, of course you can keep it that way, even though why limit yourself to India when the whole world could be downloading your app :P, Also make sure no emergency number is less than 10 digits in India.